# Question limit on Area 51?

Tags: support, questions, area-51

Why is there a question limit on Area 51?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because I was asking too many questions.

Once a given proposal has a hundred questions, few people are going to go through all of them and vote for them.  If only a few people are allowed to provide all the example questions, then the site has little "community" input - it's really being defined by a few people.

By only allowing each person to contribute 10 questions, a site needs at least 10 different people with different viewpoints to get a hundred examples.

In short, it prevents a few people from monopolizing the conversation.

Forthermore, the questions are meant to be the *defining* questions of the site.  It's easy to generate a million questions that would definitely be on the site, or definitely be off topic.  It's much harder to generate questions that intentionally explore the gray area and force people to *really* decide what the site is about.  By limiting the number of questions people can ask, it is hoped they will choose their questions more wisely<sup>*</sup>.

This problem is also helped by being able to vote on deleting poor example questions.

<sup>*<sub>Of course the most efficient method is using a binary search, and each user can, by using their 10 questions effectively, define the site accurately to the 1024th degree.</sub></sup>

Comment: So your the culprit! I might have to downvote everything you ever did. :-(

Comment: Remember to update the faq!

Comment: @Arlen - Yeah, I've got 147 example questions.  The next highest person has 116 questions, and everyone else has under 100.  I don't imagine I'm the reason they implemented the limit, but perhaps they weren't expecting to have to institute it so soon during the beta... ;-D

Comment: if it wasn't you it would have been someone else. Rate limits are our friend!

Comment: Just wait a week @Pollyanna, they'll have votes each day to upvote your great questions ;-)

Comment: @Ivo - You're just jealous you didn't think of this one first: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/164/firearms/545#545

Comment: @Pollyanna, I'm not jealous of anything: http://area51.stackexchange.com/users

Comment: @Ivo - I hope you realize my pillow is dampened by my bitter, bitter tears each night because of you.

Comment: @Pollyanna - sorry to have broken your heart...

Comment: @Ivo - That's ok, *Mr. Skeet*.