# When do we sort out the gray area questions for a proposal?

Tags: discussion, questions, area-51

There has been a lot of discussion about great on-topic and off-topic questions for a proposal.  [Joel's latest analysis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53175/area-51-new-voting-system-results) shows that Area 51 has improved the process of selecting these great example questions.  This seems to be the easy part as it is normally obvious whether a question is on-topic of off-topic.

When (or where) are the questions that fall in the [gray](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52084/question-limit-on-area51/52085#52085) [area](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52892/what-is-the-se-teams-response-to-community-feedback-on-the-new-area-51-voting-sy/52973#52973) going to be voted on or discussed?

It seems like these questions should be discussed/explored before opening the site up so there is somewhat of a consensus in the community before these types of questions get asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the beta period of a proposal an associated Meta site will be created where all of the ins and outs of everything can be discussed.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53147/what-communication-tools-do-we-have-on-area51-for-discussion-definition/53208#53208) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52562/area-51-voting-reset-and-changes).

Answer (score 2):

I think people are fooling themselves if they think that the community will not evolve over time and that the lines can be drawn beforehand.

It seems like the effort is a bit overboard with respect to question definition.